# Kubernetes Pod fails to start - Google Composer

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to set up a task in Airflow that creates a pod in Google Kubernetes from a Docker image in Registry. The task fails and returns:

```
Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start
```

Which does not say much. In a similar question, someone suggested adding a tag to the image version when using a private repository, but it did not solve the problem.

The operator is defined as:

```py
start_pod_job = GKEStartPodOperator(task_id="start_pod_job",
                                    project_id="my-project",
                                    gcp_conn_id=GCP_CONN_ID,
                                    location="us-east1-a",
                                    cluster_name="us-east-cluster-name",
                                    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                    namespace="default",
                                    image="us.gcr.io/my-project/my-image:v1",
                                    cmds=['gs://my-bucket/my-file.csv'],
                                    name="my-name")
```

The entrypoint of the image is [ "python", "./myScript.py"]. It takes as a parameter the URI of a file in Google Storage. I was able to run the image in my local machine successfully.

I'm currently using Airflow 1.10.15 and Composer 1.16.14.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try increasing `startup_timeout_seconds` value. If it doesn't help, set `is_delete_operator_pod=False` and examine gke cluster contents (eg using kubectl) during task running or after, to see if there is any error. eg. You can have ImagePullBackoff because don't have correct credential to pull image.

Comment: @Hitobat I do indeed have ImagePullBackOff. I assumed that because GCP_CONN_ID has permission to pull image, the pod would inherit it. Do I need to pass the credential as a secret to the operator?

Comment: Yes in this case you will need to specify `image_pull_secrets` param (see KubernetesPodOperator reference for all param listing). The kubernetes docs page on this topic [is here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/). Alternatively you can configure your GKE nodes with specific service account that has credentials in cluster, assuming you are not using workload identity. This would allow any host in cluster to pull docker image from your gcr registry. But maybe this is responsibility of another team depending on your org.

Comment: @Hitobat this solved my issue. Thank you!